# Replacing dependency with custom forks using pip

Tags: python, git, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I am building an app that uses `photologue` and a few other packages that have `photologue` as a dependency (e.g., `cmsplugin-photologue`). However, I need to use a modified version of `photologue` hosted on github. All this will then be deployed on Heroku, which means that installations of dependencies is done solely through a `requirements.txt` file.

In principle this is done quite easily: I can just add the repository to the requirements file  as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions) and it will be installed. The problem is that the original `photologue` is installed too and ends up the one being used.

So the general question is: Using `pip`, how can I replace an application that is a dependency of several apps with my own version of that application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use the `-U` or `--upgrade` option to replace the original package in your venv with your custom version:

```
cd myapp && venv/bin/pip install -U git+https://github.com/jcomeauictx/django-crispy-forms.git
```

then in your requirements.txt replace the line

```
django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
```

with

```
git+https://github.com/jcomeauictx/django-crispy-forms.git
```

when you push to your heroku instance, you should see something like:

```
-----> Deleting 1 files matching .slugignore patterns.
-----> Python app detected
-----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
       Uninstalling django-crispy-forms-1.4.0:
         Successfully uninstalled django-crispy-forms-1.4.0
-----> Installing dependencies with pip
       Collecting git+https://github.com/jcomeauictx/django-crispy-forms.git (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
         Cloning https://github.com/jcomeauictx/django-crispy-forms.git to /tmp/pip-AlSPnZ-build
       Installing collected packages: django-crispy-forms
         Running setup.py install for django-crispy-forms
       Successfully installed django-crispy-forms-1.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

[This section of the documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.1/usage.html#alternate-package-repositories) for an older version of PIP suggests that if PIP finds multiple definitions for a package (e.g. via `--extra-index-url` or `--find-links`), the last match will be used. Unfortunately, I cannot find this information in the current documentation, so it may have changed.

Perhaps something like this in your requirements file will work:

```
...
django-photologue
...

--find-links https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-photologue
```