# How to change the name of a third party app on Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-apps

I am using [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) and its `account` app conflicts with my `account` app.

I managed to fix this conflict by creating an app label for allauth.account based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60186153/8119664)

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AllAuthAccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'allauth.account'
    label = 'allauth_account'
    verbose_name = 'aullauth_account'
```

and then adding it to installed apps

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...,
    'apps.allauth.apps.AllAuthAccountConfig',
    ...,
)
```

Now, when I try to migrate it gives an error

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0001_initial, 0002_email_max_length in allauth_account).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'
```

but `python manage.py makemigrations --merge` also fails with the following error:

```
ValueError: Could not find common ancestor of ['0001_initial', '0002_email_max_length']
```

How can I change the allauth.account app name so it doesn't conflict with my app or my migations?

Comment: `allauth.account` has the following `("account", "0001_initial"),` as a dependency in the migration `0002_email_max_length` meaning if you change its label it will break, why don't you change your apps label instead? It's migration are in your complete control. See [ticket #23790](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23790)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I tried to change me app label, but it is a big project and it has a database that is being used. It gave me a lot of errors. Do you think it can be possible?

Comment: Ah in that case it seems it is simpler and / or easier to change allauth instead. You just might want to make your own custom fork of allauth and use that then (edit the migration files). [Replacing dependency with custom forks using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731822/replacing-dependency-with-custom-forks-using-pip) might help you on doing that if you want to.

Comment: This might be a solution. We might try it as well, and yes, I would appreciate it if you could help.

Comment: Uhh, I meant the linked question would be helpful for you. Though you can ask something if needed. Anyway all you need to do (hopefully) for code is to Change the line `("account", "0001_initial"),` in the migration, fork it and configure your requirements such that your custom fork is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can update app's verbose name in admin.py, like this

```
from django.apps import apps

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#for-application-authors

apps.get_app_config('auth').verbose_name = "Auth Management"
apps.get_app_config('admin_interface').verbose_name = "Admin Interface"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use django rename app package [package link](https://pypi.org/project/django-rename-app/). I have never use it personally but it seems to be good. you can try it