# Fork of a python library with a new name needs to appear as the original name when it’s a dependency

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

There’s an open source python library, let’s call it `foo`, and several other open source projects that depend on it, `foo-configurator`, `foo-manager`, etc.

I want to make a fork of `foo` to change the way it works under the hood (in a way that it needs to be a fork, it’s a library that interfaces with industrial hardware and we’re making one that interacts with our stuff that’s pretty different than what’s existing). So my fork would be called something like `other-foo`. The problem is I still want the other open source projects which use `foo` to be able to work with my `other-foo` as well, but they will fail on installation since their dependency check is looking `foo` and not `other-foo`.

Is there a way for me to handle this as the creator of `other-foo`, to spoof or somehow present as `foo` in terms of dependencies, but still have a package name of `other-foo`?

These foo libraries deal with industrial hardware devices, so there’s no chance that `foo` and `other-foo` will be installed at the same time.

The only way I can think to solve this would be to change the setup configurations of the other utility projects, (`foo-configurator`, etc.) to use dependency options and extras_require settings, so someone could install them in an environment with `other-foo` by using `pip install foo-configurator[other-foo]` or whatever. But that would require me to get these other projects on board, and also I think the extras_require can only *add* package dependencies to what’s already there, so them adding and extras_require for `other-foo` won’t remove the need for `foo`, so maybe that’s not the correct route?

The only other way I can think to do this is to fork all those other projects too, and change just the setup config to require `other-foo` instead of `foo`, but then I would need to maintain forks and that seems like a huge pain.

So, any ideas for the best, most pythonic way to handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: This is technically a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731822/replacing-dependency-with-custom-forks-using-pip), but I don't think the accepted answer over there is very helpful.

Comment: Good find! I just read that question, but it's not quite a dupe, since in that one the author has control over the utility packages that use the library as well, whereas in my case I do not. That said, the answer is interesting, where you essentially install the original lib along with the other apps and then replace the lib with your version, but I think that would only work if the replace lib was also called `foo` versus mine which is `other-foo`. And, ugg, then people would have to install the other lib first just for it to be removed? So, yeah, I agree the other answer isn't too helpful.

Comment: I guess, if your fork is distributed only via a different package index than the original, then you can just use the same name. -- If not; then I do not think there is a solution, `foo-manager` will only ever expect `foo` and never be satisfied with the presence of `other-foo`.